# Iterate a simple program

Tags: perl, iteration

I have the following file:

```
a b 5
c d 6
e f 7
g h 4
i j 3
k l 10
```

and I want to find which line present the minimum value in the third column and erase it from the initial file. After this, I want to iterate again the program and find again which line present the minimum and make the same thing for 2 more times.

The output file should be

```
c d 6
e f 7
k l 10
```

I tried to write the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file1 = "try.dat";
open my $fg,  "<", $file1 or die "Error during $file1 opening: $!";

my @vector;

while (<$fg>) {
    push @vector, [ split ];
}

my $minimum = $vector[0][2];
my @blacklist;
for my $i (0 .. $#vector) {
    if ($minimum > $vector[$i][2]){
    $minimum = $vector[$i][2];
    push @blacklist, @vector[$i+1]; 
    }
}
#say "my minimum is $minimum";
#say "the blacklist is composed by @blacklist";
```

I don't know how to erase the elements contained by the `@blacklist` (that in the first case should be `i j 3`) and how to iterate everything.

Any help for the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `@blacklist = @vector` you are adding the entire `@vector` array to the black list. You probably want to do a `push @blacklist, $vector[$i]`. That will push the array reference into blacklist.

Now, blacklist has an array ref in it, so you have to deference it to print it.

```
say "the blacklist is composed by @{$blacklist[0]}";
```

Edit: For iterating and writing:

I would skip the `@blacklist` array (unless you need it for something else) and remove the min values from `@vector`. Then you can write `@vector` to some file.

```
my $num_elts_to_remove = 3;
for (my $j = 0; $j < $num_elts_to_remove; $j++) {
  my $minimum = $vector[0][2];
  my $min_idx = 0;
  for my $i (0 .. $#vector) {
      if ($minimum > $vector[$i][2]){
        $minimum = $vector[$i][2];
        $min_idx = $i;
      }
  }
  push @blacklist, $vector[$min_index];
  splice @vector, $min_idx, 1; #remove array with smallest value
}
```

Now write the array to a file

```
open OUT, ">", $outfile or die "Error: $!";
foreach(@vector) {
    print OUT join " ", @$_;
    print OUT "\n";
}
close(OUT);
```

Prints:

```
c d 6
e f 7
k l 10
```

Comment: you should edit push `@blacklist, $vector[$i+1]` and it works. Any ideas on how to erase the lines from the fileand iterate it?

Comment: In the line  `splice @vector, $min_idx, 1;` what does the "1" means? How can I do if I want to use the "blacklist" array? I tried with `for my $i (0 .. $#vector) {
    if ($minimum > $vector[$i][2]){
    $minimum = $vector[$i][2];
    push @blacklist, @vector[$i+1]; 
    }
}
 splice @vector, @blacklist;` but it doesn t work

Comment: The `1` is length, or number of elements to remove. See [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html). If you want to keep a blacklist, push it before you splice it off. (see edit). `push @blacklist, $vector[$min_index];`

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is what [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) was made for. It allows you to modify the file in-place by modfying a tied array.

This program does what you want. The helper function `minidx` returns the first index of the element of the passed array that holds the smallest value.

The program works by copying the third field of the file records into array `@field3`, and finding the index of the smallest value in there. The element at that index is then deleted from both the file and `@field3` using `splice`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die $!;

my @field3 = map { (split)[2] } @file;
for (1 .. 3) {
  my $i = minidx(\@field3);
  splice @file, $i, 1;
  splice @field3, $i, 1;
}

sub minidx {
  my ($arr) = @_;
  my ($i, $v);
  for (0 .. $#$arr) {
    ($i, $v) = ($_, $arr->[$_]) unless defined $v and $arr->[$_] >= $v;
  }
  return $i;
}
```

**output**

```
c d 6
e f 7
k l 10
```

Comment: I can help but ping you. So few people appreciate Tie::File and so I thought you might like my answer too, which uses it under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Borodin's Tie::File suggestion even further. I have written a cute module called [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) which allow you to treat a delimited file as an array (and because it uses Tie::File underneath, it is both read and write). Because of this I can use Perlish operations like map and sort (and Schwartzian transform!) to perform this task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

tie my @data, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'data', sep_char => ' ';

# get a list of row ids sorted by last value (inc)
my $i = 0;
my @sorted = 
  map  { $_->[0] } 
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
  map  { [$i++, $_->[-1]] } 
  @data;

#splice the rows by index of the lowest three (from bottom to top)
splice @data, $_, 1 for reverse sort @sorted[0..2];
```

Note that in the end you want to remove rows from the bottom so that you don't have to reindex every time.